# Кнопки сдвигаются в низ при увеличении высоты блока через hover?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

У меня есть несколько карточек. В карточке есть елемент блок с картинкой обрезаная по краях 318x180   настоящий размер 350х198 заголовок  текст и кнопка прижата к низу с помощью флекс. Мне нада при увеличении блока чтоб ничего не сьежало а блок с картинкой стал под размер картинки с ефектом выхода из краем и появлением новых деталей картинки. Что я имею все кроме того что у меня сьежают все кнопки из всех блоков. Если текст отсутствует то все работает как задумано. Спасибо))
для вопроса взята картинка большего размера

Код codepen https://codepen.io/anton-mkt/pen/vYJbwdo

html

```
div class="wrapper-call__row">                          
                    <div class="wrapper-call__colum" >
                        <div class="wrapper__call">
                            <div class="call__colums_img"><img src="https://gamesqa.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sh-overview.jpg" alt=""></div>
                        
                            <div class="call__colums_title"><span>Call of Duty: WWII</span></div>
                            <div class="call__colums_text">The C.O.D.E. Bravery Pack is now available in WWII</div>
                            <div class="call_colums_button "><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-call__colum" >
                        <div class="wrapper__call">
                            <div class="call__colums_img"><img src="https://gamesqa.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sh-overview.jpg" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="call__colums_title"><span>Destiny 2</span></div>
                            <div class="call__colums_text">The C.O.D.E. Bravery Pack is now available in WWII</div>
                            <div class="call_colums_button "><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-call__colum" >
                        <div class="wrapper__call">
                        <div class="call__colums_img"><img src="https://gamesqa.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sh-overview.jpg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="call__colums_title"><span>STEEP</span></div>
                        <div class="call__colums_text"></div>
                        <div class="call_colums_button "><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="wrapper-call__colum" >
                        <div class="wrapper__call">
                            <div class="call__colums_img"><img src="https://gamesqa.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/sh-overview.jpg" alt=""></div>
                            <div class="call__colums_title"><span>Forza Motorsport 7</span></div>
                            <div class="call__colums_text"></div>
                            <div class="call_colums_button "><a href="#">See Details</a></div>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                    
            
            </div>`
```

css

```
.wrapper-call__colum {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
}

.wrapper__call {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #8DD83D;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.wrapper__call:hover {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 352px;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1);
}


.wrapper__call:hover .call__colums_img {
  height: 198px;
  width: 350px;
}

.call__colums_img {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  height: 180px;
  width: 318px;
   background: #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.call__colums_img img {
  
  position: absolute;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}

.call__colums_title {
  color: #435766;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 22px 0 0 22px;
}

.call__colums_text {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  color: #435766;
  font-size: 24px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 13px 22px 38px 22px;
}

.wrapper-call__row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.call_colums_button {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
.call_colums_button a {
  margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  width: 278px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #8DD83D;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 0 25px 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задай фиксированное позиционирование для
ховера:

```
selector:hover {
  position: fixed;
}
```